# c++ template operator overloading std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am having trouble compiling this template. I just want to create an operator whose functionality depends on the data type (int or float).
I am not an expert so I will appreciate any help.

```
template <class T> struct eq {
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type
  operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
    T* paux;
    if(sizeof(T) == 4){ //float
      uint32_t val = 0;
      if(x == y){
    val = ~val;
    T* paux = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&val);
    return *paux;
      }
      else{
    T* paux = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&val);
    return *paux;
      }
    }
    else{ //double
      uint64_t val = 0;
      if(x == y){
    val = ~val;
    T* paux = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&val);
    return *paux;
      }
      else{
        T* paux = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&val);
        return *paux;
      }
    }
  }
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type
  operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
    return (x==y) ? ~((T)(0)) : ((T)(0));
  }
};
```

Error code:

```
clases.cpp:66:3: error: ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value, T>::type eq<T>::operator()(const T&, const T&) const’ cannot be overloaded
   operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
   ^
clases.cpp:38:3: error: with ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<_Tp>::value, T>::type eq<T>::operator()(const T&, const T&) const’
   operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
```

Comment: There are no information messages or notes generated by the compiler to give more information about why you get the error? GCC and Clang (you seem to be using one of them) is very good at that. Please edit your question to include those messages as well, if you have any.

Comment: I am compiling with g++ with -std=c++11  flag. I do not get more warning messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFINAE only occurs when the template parameters are in the immediate context of a template. A simple fix for this is to make your `operator()` functions into template functions with a default argument:

```
template <class T> struct eq {
  template<typename U=T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, U>::type
  operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
    //...
  }
  template <typename U=T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value, U>::type
  operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
    //...
  }
};
```

Perhaps a slightly cleaner solution would be to provide two partial specializations of `eq`; one for floating point types and one for integral types:

```
template <class T, typename=void> struct eq;

template <class T>
struct eq<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type> {
  T operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
    //...
  }
};

template <class T>
struct eq<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type> {
  T operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {
    //...
  }
};
```